# Multi SELECT COUNT(distinct) in Pandas

Tags: python, group-by, count, distinct, pandas-groupby

In SQL:

```
SELECT distinct user_id
    , COUNT(product_id) AS c_products
    , COUNT(distinct product_id) AS c_distinct_product
FROM tables
GROUP BY user_id
```

How can I do that in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily:

```
df.groupby('user_id').agg({'product_id': ['count', pd.Series.nunique]})
```

Pandas has docs for helping with the translation from SQL to Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html

Comment: Thank you so much ,but I want to create new column, so I used `df['c_products'] = df.groupby(grouped_on)['product_id'].transform(lambda v: v.count()).astype(int)`

`df['c_distinct_product'] = df.groupby(grouped_on)['product_id'].transform(pd.Series.nunique).astype(int)'`